# CSS Footer position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, footer

i'm trying to positionate a footer (#footer) like the following:

It has to have a

```
 margin-top: 50px;
```

to the div above (#content) BUT if the div above is in the display (eg in the middle) the footer should be at least

```
 bottom:-100px;
```

AND if the div above (#content) is also out of the display (lower that bottom -100px) the footer should be under that div.

Is that possible? (if theres no other way with jq/js)

Thanks in advance for your help

**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/nU7Vh/1/
If the height of #content is for eg 300 everything is ok, but if #content (which can have variable sizes, cause its a list which is queryed) is bigger that the display the #footer isnt under the #content anymore

Comment: What do you mean by 'in the display'? Are you talking about if the browser is resized?

Comment: This is confusing. Please post more relevant code or try to explain in a different way.

Comment: @AndyG
No, the bottom line of the browser (it should be under that so that the footer is only visible if the user scrolls down)

Comment: please provide http://jsfiddle.net example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nU7Vh/1/
If the height of #content is for eg 300 everything is ok, but if #content (which can have variable sizes, cause its a list which is queryed) is bigger that the display the #footer isnt under the #content anymore

Comment: Try removing `position:absolute;` on `#footer`

Comment: @DanielLisik then its not guaranteed, that the footer is not in the middle of the page, if the ocntent is only 1-2 lines

Comment: @communications how about using JS to check the height of `#content` and then decide what to do depending on height?

Comment: So js is the only way to do it?

Comment: @communications I think so yes, but I'm no CSS guru so there may very well be CSS pure solutions for this.

Comment: Ok, thank you Daniel Lisik

Comment: @communications wait I think I have it. How far down you want the footer minimum if #content is short?

Comment: @communications see here: http://jsfiddle.net/nU7Vh/3/ You can change the `min-height` property on `#meta_content` if you would like a specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Remove the following 2 lines from `#footer`:

```
position:absolute;
bottom:-100px;
```

**2.** Add a container div to `#content`, which will (unlike `#content`, which may have any height as you stated) have a `min-height` of *100%* of the screen (you can of course change *100%* to a different percentage if you like).

```
 <div id="meta_content">
     <div id="content">
     </div>
 </div>
```

**3.** Add this CSS, which makes the `min-height` magic happen:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

#meta_content { min-height:100%; }
```

**[jsFiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/nU7Vh/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

You could use a wrapper element (*with `min-height:100%`*), and not use absolute positioning.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{height:100%;}
.wrap{min-height:100%;}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/rXZkx/

Answer (score 0):

You must configure a surrounding element (e.g. HTML) to fill at minimum the height of the window and allow an inner one (e.g. BODY) to overflow when higher:

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    height: 100%; /* fill up window height and let body overflow if higher */
}
body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50px; /* space for footer */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* padding should not be added to height, but included in height */
}
#content {
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
    background: blue;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#footer {
    height: 18px;
    width: 500px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x4TPf/